# Is there a hotkey for searching for references in IntelliJ when using Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a hotkey for searching for references in IntelliJ when using Scala?

In Eclipse, when using the hotkey CTRL+SHIFT+G on a name, a search for references starts. This is very usefull to find where a certain method is used. Is there anything similiar in IntelliJ when using Scala ?

Comment: Try Alt+F7, should do the trick

Comment: Also try Alt+H when you're standing on the method name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>: Show Usages; displays pop-up with usages.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>: Find Usages; opens the *Find* view, displaying usages in various ways (such as by methods and by files).

Found by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then typing *find*, and seeing *Show Usages* and *Find Usages* listed. I tried *search* first, but that only showed settings. Now, I knew IDEA called it *Usages*, not *References*, but I avoided searching for that because you wouldn't know to search for that.

Comment: Looks like you can also right click on a class and select find "usages"
see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622519/finding-all-references-to-an-object-in-idea

Answer (score 2):

I think in version 12 in Ubuntu Linux it's Control + Alt + the number key 7 rather than F7.