# Finding all references to an Object in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, find-all-references

Is there a shortcut key or an option for Intellij-IDEA IDE to find all references to a `Class` in a particular project? For example, I have created my own `Class` to hold a `String` and an `int` and I have made references through the project. The project is quite large and I don't want to have to search through each file manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do is Right-click on the `Class` and select *Find usages*, or Alt+F7. Here is a more detailed description http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/finding-usages-in-project.html.